# What is the point of public field declarations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) docs :

```
class Rectangle {
  height = 0;
  width;
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

> By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more
> self-documenting, and the fields are always present.
>
> As seen above, the fields can be declared with or without a default
> value.

At first I thought that if I create an object using the constructor above and don't pass **height** and **width** arguments, I would have `height = 0`. However, it's not a case. It is `undefined`.

```
let rectangle = new Rectangle()

console.log(rectangle.height) // this is undefined
```

So, now I can't understand the point of public field declarations. They look like extra lines of code without much of  purpose.  What benefits do they bring? Thanks for  any explanations.

Comment: Your code `this.height = height` is replacing the default value with the value from the function parameter. If you don't provide the argument, the parameter becomes undefined.

Comment: `constructor(height, width) { console.log({height, width}); .....`

Comment: The lines you quoted explain the purpose of the variable declarations. But there's little point in declaring a default value for a variable that's always set in the constructor.

Comment: @Barmar I guess the example they provide is very confusing. There is no point in declaring height as a public field and then using it in a constructor, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning to the `height` in the constructor, effectively overriding the class field assignment:

```
this.height = height;
```

Class fields assign properties to the instance before the constructor body runs, for the most part - your original code is nearly equivalent to

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = 0;
    this.width;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
let rectangle = new Rectangle()

console.log(rectangle.height)
```

which should make the issue obvious.

> They look like extra lines of code without much of purpose.

Yes, if you assign to those properties in the constructor unconditionally, having such fields doesn't help much - it'll tell readers of the code *quickly* what instance properties will exist, but it also means additional code.

Class fields are much more useful when you want to assign instance properties that *don't* get immediately overwritten, such as:

```js
class Rectangle {
  height = 5;
  constructor(width) {
    this.width = width;
  }
}
let rectangle = new Rectangle(8)

console.log(rectangle.height, rectangle.width)
```

Class fields are nice syntax sugar when you have multiple properties to assign to the instance that don't depend on constructor arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The line `this.height = height;` replaces the default value from the declaration with the value of the `height` parameter. It makes no difference that no argument was supplied, it still performs the assignment. And when the argument isn't supplied, the parameter defaults to `undefined`.

You could check for this and not override the initial default:

```
class Rectangle {
  height = 0;
  width;
  constructor(height, width) {
    if (height !== undefined) {
      this.height = height;
    }
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Or you could provide the defaults in the constructor argument list instead of the property declarations.

```
class Rectangle {
  height;
  width;
  constructor(height = 0, width = 0) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```